# How to apply custom jQuery plugin to more than one element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I have made a jQuery plugin that works fine when applied to a single element.
When I apply it to another element the previous stops behaving like it should.
This way, only the last element applied is working.
What showld I consider when developing the plugin to create the premises for this to work for all elements?

This is the way I made the plugin:

```
 (function($) {  

      $.fn.scrollabix = function(params) {

        return this.each(function(){
               // my code
            });           

      };  

 })(jQuery);
```

This is the entire code:

```
(function($) {  
        // jQuery plugin definition  
        $.fn.scrollabix = function(params) {

            return this.each(function(){

                // OPTIONS/Config
                    $defaultOptions = 
                                        {
                                            direction: 'vertical'
                                        };
                    $.extend($defaultOptions, params);

                // LOCAL PARAMETERS
                    $self = $(this);
                    $scrolled = $("> div", this);                   

                // GET INFO
                    $selfHeight  = parseInt($self.css("height"));
                    $scrolledHeight = parseInt($('> div', $self).css("height"));

                    $selfWidth  = parseInt($self.css("width"));
                    $scrolledWidth = parseInt($('> div', $self).css("width"));

                    $leftOutside = ($scrolledHeight) - parseInt($selfHeight) /*+ 50*/;  // user for Vertivcal only


                // PLUGIN ACTIONS
                    actions = {
                        continous : 0,
                        slideUp : function(q)
                        {
                            if($leftOutside > 0)
                            {
                                slideBy =(120 * 20) / q;

                                currTop = parseInt($scrolled.css("top"));
                                absCurrTop = Math.abs(currTop);

                                if(absCurrTop + slideBy > ($leftOutside))
                                {
                                    $scrolled.stop().animate({top : '-' + $leftOutside + 'px'}, 250);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if(absCurrTop < ($leftOutside))
                                    {
                                        $scrolled.stop().animate({top : '-=' + slideBy}, 250, 'linear', function(){
                                            if(actions.continous == 1)
                                            {
                                                actions.slideUp(q);
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                }                           
                            }
                        },
                        slideDown : function(q)
                        {
                            if($leftOutside > 0)
                            {
                                slideBy =(120 * 20) / q;

                                currTop = parseInt($scrolled.css("top"));
                                absCurrTop = Math.abs(currTop);

                                if(absCurrTop - slideBy < 0)
                                {
                                    slideBy = absCurrTop;
                                }
                                if(currTop < 0)
                                {
                                    $scrolled.stop().animate({top : '+=' + slideBy}, 250, 'linear', function(){
                                        if(actions.continous == 1)
                                        {
                                            actions.slideDown(q);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        slideLeft : function(q)
                        {
                            if($leftOutside > 0)
                            {
                                consolex('slideLeft');
                            }                           
                        },
                        slideRight : function(q)
                        {
                            if($leftOutside > 0)
                            {
                                consolex('slideRight');
                            }
                        }
                    }

                // CREATE INFRASTRUCTURE
                    $self.css({
                        overflow : 'hidden',
                        position : 'relative'
                    });
                    $scrolled.css({
                        position : 'absolute',
                        top : '0px',
                        left : '0px'
                    });

                    if($defaultOptions.direction == 'vertical')
                    {
                        $self.mousemove(function(e){
                            var x = parseInt(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft);
                            var y = parseInt(e.pageY - this.offsetTop);

                            if(y > ($selfHeight - 120) && y < $selfHeight)
                            {
                                actions.continous = 1;
                                actions.slideUp($selfHeight - y);
                            }
                            else if(y < 120 && y >= 1)
                            {
                                actions.continous = 1;
                                actions.slideDown(y);           
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                actions.continous = 0;
                            }
                        }).mouseout(function(){
                            actions.continous = 0;
                        });
                    }
                    else if ($defaultOptions.direction == 'horizontal')
                    {

                        $leftOutside = $scrolledWidth - $selfWidth;                     

                        $self.mousemove(function(e){
                            $scrolledWidth = parseInt($scrolled.css('width'));

                            var x = parseInt(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft);
                            $selfWidth = parseInt($self.css("width"));
                            $leftOutside = ($scrolledWidth) - parseInt($selfWidth);
                            consolex($leftOutside);

                            if(x < 300 && x >= 1)
                            {
                                actions.continous = 1;
                                actions.slideRight(x);                              
                            }
                            else if( x > $selfWidth - 300)
                            {
                                actions.continous = 1;
                                actions.slideLeft(x);                               
                            }

                        }).mouseout(function(){
                            actions.continous = 0;
                        });
                    }
                //return this;
            });           
        };  
    })(jQuery);
```

Comment: You probably have some assumptions in `//my code` that only considers a single element..

Comment: Can you provide more code? The basic structure of the plugin seems correct, I don't have enough details to work on.

Comment: It seems to me the most important code related to your problem would be the code you've omitted, where you have `// my code`. Post that and we may be able to help you figure it out.

Comment: jQuery is designed to work as in your code snippet, regardless of whether the collection contains zero, one, or many elements. Can you be more specific as to what is going wrong? Include more code, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing the right way using `this.each()` inside the plugin and applying the logic on each element. If you are messing up inside `each` block then that might create problem.

Answer (score 2):

take a look at these links to organize your plugin

http://addyosmani.com/blog/essential-jquery-plugin-patterns/
http://alexsexton.com/?p=51
http://jqueryboilerplate.com/

they all represents a modern and scalable approach for plugin creation

Comment: He built the `plugin` in the right way already. His problem isn't the `plugin` part.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the pattern described [jQuery Boilerplate](http://jqueryboilerplate.com/). The pattern uses [prototypical inheritance](http://alexsexton.com/?p=51), that can ensure that a new instance of the plugin is instantiated on each element. The key to this is these lines:

```
// A really lightweight plugin wrapper around the constructor, 
// preventing against multiple instantiations
$.fn[pluginName] = function ( options ) {
    return this.each(function () {
        if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)) {
            $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName, new Plugin( this, options ));
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're overwriting your global variables on each loop iteration. Add `var` to each variable that is meant to be used locally, e.g `$self`, `$scrolled` etc.